# CakePHP 2.2.2 Asset Compress CssMinFilter Comments Issue

Tags: cakephp, plugins, sass

I am using JsMinFilter & CssMinFilter to compress all my CSS and JS files into one output file. This works fine for both, however the JS filter that I found a modified copy of somewhere, lets you keep important comments, e.g. copyright notices.

I know that there is a filter option for the CssMinFilter that can set the RemoveComments to false. However I can't seem to find any information about where I set that option when I am using this with CakePHP (ver 2.2.2), any one know where? Do I put it in my AppController or is it another config file I have to make for it?

Also I do have access to SASS and I know that there should be a filter for the Asset Compress to use to build my SASS files into css and then output as one file again. The Wiki on the plugin page for the Asset Compress is not detailed about where I can get this or how to plug it into my site, like the CssMinFilter?

Many Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got a answer to some of it! Still do not know about how to important a SASS filter into CakePHP, so I will keep looking at that.

I have now moved to the YUI Compressor to do my CSS, which keeps all '!' marked comments within the file.

I also know that you can use this for the JavaScript, however when I do, it processes 6 errors when you add the Jquery  and Jquery UI to the build, so for now I am still using the JsMinFilter.

I will repost a new question about eh YUI Compressor issue with my Jquery build.

Many Thanks

Glenn.